# AutoCAD dimensions units

Tags: autocad, units, autocad-map, dimensions

Not sure if this question belongs (Please tell me if it isn't)

I have an AutoCAD drawing that is in centimeters, and every time I insert a dimension, it appears in centimeters (which makes sense since the unit is set to centimeters in "Drawing Utilities") **but** is there a way to make the dimensions appear in meters while keeping the unit system in the drawing in centimeters?

*I Use AutoCAD 2014

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CAD drafting software with no apparent GIS component.

Comment: I will add that yes, you can specify a different unit in your dim style than that used in the actual drawing file. It should be pretty easy to figure out from the help files, but I haven't touched AutoCAD in a while and I don't recall the exact steps/dialog and it might have changed with the interface.

Comment: Format>Drawing Units Length Angle etc can be changed. AutoCAD Map 3D is a full GIS http://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad-map-3d/overview

Comment: @mapperz I believe that would change the actual file units, not just the dimension units, which the asker specifically said he did NOT want to do. And yes, *Map 3D* is a GIS, but this particular question doesn't seem related to any GIS function, just a drafting one. I view it as similar to all the Python and Excel related questions that get closed; opinions may differ of course.

Comment: @ChrisW
Thanks for the reply
I checked all the options in the "Dimension style" window but found no way of changing units.
Source: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-dimension-style-in-autocad-2014.html

Comment: Never mind
I just found a simple way (hack?) that does the job
Check the second answer from the following link.
Source: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100727193406AAKhHkE

Comment: I just saw that one myself. That shows you the list of styles, but you have to select and modify or create one to get to the real settings. I think you'd want something on the Primary Units or Alternate units tabs.